# How can i get the Log on id from the whoami.exe result in c# code

Tags: c#

if i open the cmd and type `whoami/logonid` i get back a Logon id number ,

after some research i found this line :

```
var logonId = UserPrincipal.Current.Sid;
```

this code gets me a number that starts like the whoami/lgonid
but they different.

i dont wish to run the whoami throw c# code 
i just need to get the result number.

for example : 
if i write whoami/user i got the user name, the equivalent in c# code is  `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;`

i need the same for logonid

Comment: If you use `whoami /user` you get the same SID as from the API. I wonder what the difference is from `/user` and `/logonid`

Comment: me to, /user giving me the same as the code i wrote in the question 
/logonid giving me different number

Comment: Seems like `/logonid` gives you a session id that changes whenever you log out and back in. You can get the logon id using the GetTokenInformation function in advapi32.dll, but that's unmanaged code so more difficult to call than managed code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput` when you instantiate whoami. You can parse the text you get for the logonid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardoutput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx) Property to achieve this.

Following is sample code:

```
public static string GetLoginId()
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    p.Start();

    StreamWriter myStreamWriter = p.StandardInput;
    myStreamWriter.WriteLine("whoami /logonid");

    // To avoid deadlocks, always read the output stream first and then wait.
    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Comment: this code do not work for me.

Comment: and i dont wont to run the whoami.exe i just wont the retrun number

Comment: for example if i write whoami in cmd i get the computer username 
the equivalent in c# code is :  WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name

Comment: +1 for the efforts. @B.katan: You should have indicateed in the OP that you do not want to execute whoami. From your wording I -and apparently others as well- gathered that you are looking for a solution to invoke whoami and parse the result.

Comment: you  right , i edited the question